# Infinite sum of $cot^{-1}$ series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

If $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty cot^{-1}\left(2 + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)=tan^{-1}a$$, then 'a' is equal to
(A) 1
(B) 2
(C) 3
(D) 4

My aproach in such question is to break orignal function into difference of two functions using identies

$cot^{-1}(\frac{xy+1}{x-y}) = cot^{-1}x - cot^{-1}y$

In this $n^{2} + n + 4$ cannot be changed to xy+1

Is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193001/explicitly-finding-the-sum-of-arctan1-n2n1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415512/is-s-sum-r-1-infty-tan-1-frac2r2r2r4-finite  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144944/finding-tan-t-if-t-sum-tan-11-2t2/761847#761847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$\cot(A-B)=\dfrac{\cot A\cot B+1}{\cot B-\cot A}$

and 
$$\dfrac{4+n(n+1)}2=\dfrac{1+\dfrac n2\cdot\dfrac{n+1}2}{\dfrac{n+1}2-\dfrac n2}$$