# Find the value of infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan^{-1}(2/n^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, limits-without-lhopital

Find the value of infinite series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{n^2} \right) $$

I tried to find sequence of partial sums and tried to find the limit of that sequence. But I didn't get the answer.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this problem goes back to Ramanujan. And it can be computed using telescoping technique combined with the following identity: $$ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{2}{n^2}\right). $$

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144944/finding-tan-t-if-t-sum-tan-11-2t2,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415512/is-s-sum-r-1-infty-tan-1-frac2r2r2r4-finite   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617032/calculation-of-int-01-tan-11-xx2dx

Comment: Also an elementary approach is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053616/find-sum-n-1-infty-tan-1-frac2n2/3053632#3053632). It is works from the vein that @SangchulLee pointed out.

Answer (score 7):

It's the argument of the complex number
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{2i}{n^2}\right)
=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n-1+i)(n+1-i)}{n^2}
=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n-1+i)(n^2+2n)}{n^2(n+1+i)}.$$
This infinite product telescopes.

Comment: Briefly, how did you get the first step? :(

Comment: @JoaoNoch, It follows from $ \arctan(x) = \arg(1+ix)$. Perhaps the only non-trivial part is that the argument of the product above determines OP's sum only modulo $2\pi$. But an estimate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan(2/n^2) \leq \frac{\pi}{2} + 2(\zeta(2)-1) < \pi$$ shows that the principal argument function is enough for our purpose.