# How to evaluate this $\int_{-1}^1 (\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x})\arctan\frac{2}{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, inverse-function, trigonometric-integrals

I dont know how to evaluate this improper integral:
$$I=\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right )\arctan\frac{2}{x^2}dx$$
At first I tried to do it in trigonometric substitution：$x=\sin t,dx=\cos tdt$
$$I=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\csc t+1-\cot t\right)\arctan(2\csc ^2t)\cos tdt$$
$$=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\cot t+\cos t-\cot t\cos t\right)\arctan(2\csc ^2t)dt$$
I don't know what to do next,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427602/find-the-value-of-infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-tan-12-n2#comment5014314_2427602

Comment: Thank you for the link, but that is a sum,but does that have anything to do with the integral?

Comment: Write $$\arctan\dfrac2{x^2}=\arctan\dfrac1{x-1}-\arctan\dfrac1{x+1}$$

Comment: @,Thanks for your hint,I'll try trying.

Comment: $\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right )\arctan\frac{2}{x^2}$ is an odd function and it's continue at $x=0$

Comment: @FDP,Yes I see,thanks a lot ,is there a similar amazing step next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x}\right)\arctan{\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-1}^{0}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x}\right)\arctan{\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x}\right)\arctan{\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(-\frac{1}{x}+1+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x}\right)\arctan{\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[x\mapsto-x\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x}\right)\arctan{\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\arctan{\left(\frac{2}{x^{2}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

In other words, only the even components of the integrand contribute to value of the integral because of the symmetry of the limits of integration.

---

Comment: ,Wow,beautifull answer,great! thank you very much, and then what to do next?

Comment: @JamesJ Integration by parts is one possibility. That gives you an integral of a simple rational function, so the final answer will be in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

Let me write a complete answer：
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{1}{x}+1-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)\arctan\left(\frac{2}{x^2}\right)dx\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\arctan\left(\frac{2}{x^2}\right)dx\qquad(\text odd function)\\
&=\int_0^2\arctan\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}dx\\
&=\int_0^2\arctan\frac{x+(2-x)}{1-x(2-x)}dx\\
&=\int_0^2(\arctan x+\arctan(2-x))dx\\
&=2\int_0^2\arctan xdx\\
&=2(x\arctan x|_0^2-\int_0^2\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx)\\
&=4\arctan 2-\ln (1+x^2)|_0^2\\
&=4\arctan 2-\ln 5
\end{align}