# How do we find the value of $\tan\biggr(\sum_{1\leq i\leq 21}f(i)\biggr)$ if $f(x) = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^{2 }+ x + 1}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Let's assume that $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ such that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \arctan\biggr(\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\biggr)$. How can we find $\tan\biggr(\sum_{1\leq i\leq 21}f(i)\biggr)$?

Below is a fact that I've derived:

$$\tan\biggr(f(x)+f(x+1)\biggr) = \frac{\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+(x+1)+1}+\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}}{1-\frac{1}{((x+1)^2+(x+1)+1)(x^2+x+1)}} = \frac{2}{(x+1)^2}$$

But I am not sure how this can be used to approach the problem.

Comment: Hint: What’s $\arctan(x+1)-\arctan(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

As @TheBestMagician has mentioned, notice that:
\begin{align*}
\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^{2} + x + 1}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{(x + 1) - x}{1 + (x + 1)x}\right) = \arctan(x + 1) - \arctan(x)
\end{align*}

Based on such identity, the proposed sum telescopes.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to TheBestMagician's comment.

Hint (almost solution).

The problem is alike [Finding $\tan t$ if $t=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\bigl(\frac{1}{2i^2}\bigr)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144944/finding-tan-t-if-t-sum-i-1-infty-tan-1-bigl-frac12i2-bigr?rq=1)

$$\arctan x-\arctan y=\arctan\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)$$
hence $f(x) = arctan (x+1) - arctan(x)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = arctan(n+1)-arctan(1)$.